# How to search customer by billing phone In Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to do a woocommerce client search, using metadata like billing_phone or billing_address or another metadata.

The only thing I found is that you can search by nickname first name or email.

Answer (score 0):

This code allow to search a customer by metadata… I have customized `searchform.php` in Wordpress for use native searcher:

```
<h3>buscar por otro termino (direccion , telefono, ciudad , etc)</h3>
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="<?php echo site_url('/'); ?>">
    <div class="user-form">
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
    </div>
</form> 

<?php
if( $_GET['s'] ) {

    $search_term = sanitize_text_field( stripslashes( $_GET['s']));


// WP_User_Query arguments
  $args = array (
        'role'       => 'customer',
        'order'      => 'asc',
        'orderby'    => 'display_name',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'or',
            array(
                'key'     => 'nickname',
                'value'   => $search_term,
                'compare' => 'like'
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'last_name',
                'value'   => $search_term,
                'compare' => 'like'
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'billing_phone',
                'value'   => $search_term,
                'compare' => 'like'
           ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'billing_address_1',
                'value'   => $search_term,
                'compare' => 'like'
           )

        )
    );

// Create the WP_User_Query object
$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

// Get the results
$authors = $wp_user_query->get_results();

// Check for results
if ( ! empty( $authors ) ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    // loop through each author
    foreach ( $authors as $author ) {
        // get all the user's data
        $author_info = get_userdata( $author->ID );


        echo '<li>' . $author_info->nickname . ' ' . $author_info->last_name . '</li>';

                echo '<li>' . $author_info->billing_phone . '</li><br>';
                 echo '<li>' . $author_info->billing_address_1 . '</li><br>';


  echo '<a href="'. um_user_profile_url( $author->ID ) .'">'. esc_attr( $author_info->user_nicename ) .'</a>';
  //echo '<a href="'. /user( $author->ID ) .'">'. esc_attr( $author_info->user_nicename ) .'</a>';

    }
    echo '</ul>';
} 

else {
    echo 'No authors found';
}

}
?>
```